# DrawerLayout NavigationView one menu item needs to be higher than the rest

Tags: android, dynamic, height, drawerlayout, navigationview

How can i make one menu item have more height than the rest. Im using custom layout for the menu item

```
<item
    app:actionLayout="@layout/drawer_layout_location"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_location_on_black_24dp"
    tools:ignore="MenuTitle"
    />
```